# Show hide elements on button click in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show/hide elements on button click. Below are the code which I have written so far. I am facing trouble while writing Angular code due to lack of knowledge.

What I want to achieve is: I have 3 text boxes first box will be visible by default as soon user click on `+` button. Second text box will visible and same for third. To remove the boxes I have created a `-` button. So, as soon user click on `-` button last box will be hidden.

```
<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity }">
<input name="city" id="city" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
</div>


<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button><br>

<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity1 }">
<input name="city1" id="city1" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city1">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity1}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
</div>


<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button><br>


<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity }">
<input name="city2" id="city2" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city2">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity2">{{errorcity2}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
</div>


<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
```

I don't have anything under addNewChoice() and removeChoice().

Comment: It looks like you know about the `ng-show` directive. Can you think of a way of using that to hide or show something based on a scope property? Then you can change the property in your methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to create an array loop it using `ng-repeat`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.arr = [{'city':'city1' },{'city':'city2' }];

$scope.addNewChoice = function(){
  $scope.arr.push({'city':'' })
}

$scope.removeChoice = function(index){
  $scope.arr.splice(index,1)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
 <div ng-repeat="item in arr">     <br>

  <div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity1 }">
  <input name="city1" id="city1" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="item.city">
  <div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity1}}</div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
  <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>

</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried it already but i don't want to use it. i am looking for simple show hide not loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use an array of objects. For add use `push` and for remove use `splice`. Check this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.errorcity = "";
    $scope.jobs = [{text:""}];
    
    $scope.removeChoice = function(ind){
      $scope.jobs.splice(ind,1);
    }
    $scope.addNewChoice = function(){
      $scope.jobs.push({text:""});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="j in jobs track by $index">
<div class="col-xs-10">
<div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity }">
<input name="city" ng-model="j.text" id="city" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity}}</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>
</div>
<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button><br>
</div>
</div>
```